# Took the liberty of vs Took the liberty for

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm not sure which sentence to use:

- I've took the liberty **of** **doing** it. vs
- I've took the liberty **to** **do** it.

The complete context would be:

> Last month we discussed adding a paragraph about worms in the
>   third chapter. I've **took the liberty** ________.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not idiomatic to say *I've took the liberty*. Instead, it's either *I've taken the liberty* or *I took the liberty*. The last part of the sentence can be either *of doing* or *to do*.

As such, there are four possible variations, all of which sound natural:

> I've taken the liberty of doing it.
>   I've taken the liberty to do it.
>   I took the liberty of doing it.
>   I took the liberty to do it.

Which of those four should be used is a matter of style and personal choice.

---

All four versions could also be expressed with a single variation that doesn't include the taking of liberty:

> I went ahead and did it.

Comment: Thank you for explanaing it. Is there any difference for a native speaker?

Comment: @xuxuxu Not in terms of essential meaning, no. Probably *of doing* is more common since it's simply easier to say than is *to do it*. Between *taken* and *took*, perhaps *taken* would be used as a simple description of the situation (*I've taken the liberty of emptying the trash*) and *took* as a kind of criticism of somebody else when trying to fix their mistake (*I took the liberty to spell check your text*)—but I'm reaching with that. (And I can't offer any objective evidence for the intuition.)

Answer (score 1):

The expression is:

> I've **taken** the liberty **of** doing it.

Or, using the simple past:

> **I took** the liberty of doing it.

Comment: Why taken instead of took in the first example?

Comment: @xuxuxu - See [_Not So Fast_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) on our meta site. (It’s doubly true when not all your questions have been answered.)